# Orbeon Forms: Issue Calling a URL

Tags: orbeon

We want to have a URL option on our form and we used this [reference](https://gist.github.com/avernet/2a2c50d84116f2337b68c4c6acc730cc).

And we want to call a URL with this format:

vsm-go://?portalURL=https://webgis.mappingsys.myCompany.MyCompantArea/portal&app=fad235c399a04e76b9629e5ae0571c0f&workflow=21779c3a-6397-4d5e-867d-628d11f55fdb&workflowParams={order:10000123}

However, this URL does not get triggered from the form - the system appears to see it as a string, not a URL.

If you paste the URL into Safari, then it works perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a Formatted Text Area field? Does it look like a link? Are you saying you can copy that link from the output and paste it into Safari and it works?

Comment: The Formatted Text Area takes up too much space, so we want to use a button, but this doesn't work on the Mobile device (it's OK on in Test and Offline Test modes). 
So our fallback option was to use a Text Field, Explanatory Text or Calculated Text control using this option:
https://gist.github.com/avernet/2a2c50d84116f2337b68c4c6acc730cc
However, the URLs do not open directly from the link in the form.
If we drag the link to a text field, then select all the text, then use the Open Link option, then the link does open OK in Safari on the mobile device.

Comment: Test form:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/13f71d1770bed6ab21a1173645f03605db6f2e7e?form-version=1

Comment: Update:

I have successfully downloaded the desktop version of **VertiGIS Studio Go** onto my laptop, and I can confirm that test URLs in the Dynamic Form correctly opens the VertiGIS Studio Go app when tested via Online/Offline Test modes in a browser.
So this is a device issue, not a general Dynamic Form issue.

Comment: This also works for me if I load a form from an actual iPhone: the URL then opens the native app. I suspect that this is simply not supported in the context of Orbeon Forms embedded within a web view within a native app, without specific support enabled or implemented in that native app.